# GetFeature request issue with WFS

Tags: wfs, getfeature

I have this WFS: [http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=vg1000:vg1000_sta&MAXFEATURES=5&BBOX=47.567208267268484,10.44518218531835,48.949175304644434,13.626305641159272,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4258](http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=vg1000:vg1000_sta&MAXFEATURES=5&BBOX=47.567208267268484,10.44518218531835,48.949175304644434,13.626305641159272,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4258&)

As you can see, the version requested is 2.0.0 so the key for limiting the number of feature types as result should be `COUNT` and not `MAXFEATURES` which is for the earlier WFS versions. `COUNT` does not work but `MAXFEATURES` is working fine. Very strange...

when clicking on the same link fot the request, BBOX is actually not returning the elements in the BBOX but all the elements... the BBOX is not working properly.

Is there something that I am missing here with this service, or is the service in a bad shape?

Comment: Fix the typo BBOW=BBOX=

Comment: For me it seems that COUNT and STARTINDEX do work. Try http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=vg1000:vg1000_sta&startindex=4&count=4

Comment: @user30184 Count doesn't work for me if I don't use the optional STARTINDEX though~ http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=vg1000:vg1000_sta&count=4& so the service does seem to be non-compliant

Answer (score 1):

The service does not seem to be fully compliant to the WFS 2.0.0 specification.

We can see in comments that `startindex` and `count` together seem to work:

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=vg1000:vg1000_sta&startindex=4&count=4&
```

but count without startindex doesn't (4 asked for 9 returned):

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=vg1000:vg1000_sta&startindex=4&count=4&
```

We can see that a Capabilities with AcceptVersions that doesn't give an available version doesn't give an error (it should)...

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&acceptversions=1.1.2,2.0.2&
```

or even if we give an available option it doesn't return it...

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wfs_vg1000?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&acceptversions=1.0.0,2.0.2&
```

I'm not sure if I'd go as far as saying it's in 'bad shape', because mostly it works, though that would be a personal opinion.